# how to implement protocol buffering in android

Tags: android

Currently  we have the requirement to implement the protocol buffering for server communication. Can somebody provide me any input if , they have regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look on the following link for protocol buffer.
http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html

Create a thread which will read data from server. read the data in inputstram and then deserialize the data. Use Message class.

Thanks
Deepak